# Erro runat=server ao inserir um botão no form

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estou com esse problema que ao passar do form de login ele da esse erro:

```
[HttpException (0x80004005): Controle 'Button1' do tipo 'Button' deve ser inserido em uma marca de formato com runat=server.]
```

Como ja identifiquei que seria os botoes que nao deixam iniciar: asp:Button

Logo testei com outros containers e tambem dao o mesmo erro, nao consegui achar solução pra isso, tirando usar outro tipo, por exemplo html, mas como estou desenvolvendo no asp.net c# nao teria muito sentido eu usar ele ja que vou fazer todo back em c#. Gostaria de saber uma forma de resolver isso:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="mapa.aspx.cs" Inherits="MapaAs.mapa" %>

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="screen"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/botao.css" media="screen"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/all-animation.css">
 <script src="java/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
 <title>MAPA DE LEITOS ALPHA</title>
<style type="text/css">

     </style>
 </head>
  <body>
   <script src="java/tooltip.js"></script>

    <div id="section" runat=server>
            <div id="header">


            <form id="logoSBC">
            </form>
            <form id="logoUPA">
            </form>

            <div id="cabeca2">
            UPA ALVES DIAS
            </div>
            </div><!--Fim da header--><!--onMouseOver="toolTip('Lag', 150,100)" onMouseOut="toolTip()"-->
        <div id="navleitos">    
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
        </div><!--FINAL LEITOS-->

<div id="Plantoes" style="display:none">
    <asp:Table ID="plantao" runat="server" Width="86px">
<asp:TableRow>
    <asp:TableCell>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat=server Text="Médicos:"></asp:Label>
    </asp:TableCell>
</asp:TableRow>
    </asp:Table>
    </div>


 </div><!--FIM DA VIDA-->
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com o *ASP.Net WebForms*, todos os controles servidor (`runat="server"`) devem ficar dentro de uma tag `<form runat="server">`.

Para resolver seu problema, insira o conteúdo da sua página dentro de um `<form runat="server">`.

O problema disso é que não poderá ter outras tag `<form>` aninhadas. Existem [alguns hacks](http://www.frederikvig.com/2009/06/using-multiple-forms-on-an-asp-net-web-forms-page/) para permitir mais de um form com WebForms, mas conceitualmente isso não é permitido. Se precisa realmente ter mais de uma tag `<form>`, terá que usar o *ASP.Net MVC*.

Comment: É isso que da desenvolver um sistema para uma rede de pronto atendimento de saude em uma linguagem desconhecida :/. Valeu man kkkkk Funcinou

Comment: Ótimo! Já que a resposta lhe foi útil, não esqueça de escolher como certa. Leia mais em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers